# Unable to connect to GCP Cloud MySQL instance from containerized springboot application

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, google-cloud-platform

I have a spring boot application that connects to a GCP Cloud MySQL database. My application.properties file looks like below:

```
# Data source configurations
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=dbname
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=instance-name
```

I am now trying to containerize this spring boot application using the below Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ./target/ecommerce-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

I am able to build the docker image successfully, however, when I try to run a container from the image, I get the below exception:

```
2023-11-15 13:29:28 java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
2023-11-15 13:29:28     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:111) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
2023-11-15 13:29:28     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:98) ~[mysql-connector-j-
.....`
```

I have authorized all ips(0.0.0.0/0) in my DB instance's Authorized Networks.

What could be the issue. Kindly guide me.

Comment: how are you trying to connect to the database, with simple username password? Also, where does the application run and is the database private or public?

Comment: The database is a Google Cloud MySQL Database and the spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name in my application.properties points to the GCP instance name. 
I am running this application locally by containerising it using docker. The DB is public and I am able to connect without trouble if I run it in my localhost. I get this problem only after containerising.

Comment: Then it probably cannot resolve the host name of the remote server within the docker network.